# How to add placeholder images from Imageholdr?

Tags: image, generator, placeholder

I am a new developer and i searched for tools that i can use to design websites more efficient, and i came across http://imageholdr.com, anyone used it before? They say that i can add pictures easy on my website without downloading them or so.

I tried to use http://imageholdr.com/500x500 and it worked on my website, but i want to use category and it doesn't work i don't know why can anyone help me setup this? The site instructions are that i must use

http:// imageholdr.com/500x500/category/cars/ but it doesn't work. Any solution? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misread the instructions. The correct url is just http://imageholdr.com/500x500/cars/.

Comment: Oh :o ok now it works, thank you very much and sorry i am still a beginner.